# CWWAM0003E - Exception occurred while validating an annotation: com.ibm.wsspi.amm.validate.ValidationException

Tags: spring, validation, ejb-3.0, spring-annotations

***Integrating EJB3 with Spring***

**Bean.xml looks like below -**

`<bean id="perilEjbReference"     class="org.springframework.ejb.access.LocalStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/perilEJB3/PerilStatelessSessionBean"/>
        <property name="businessInterface" value="perilEJB3.PerilStatelessSessionBeanLocal"/>
    </bean>`

**Client Class looks like below -**

```
PerilStatelessSessionBeanLocal perilEjbReference;

public PerilStatelessSessionBeanLocal getPerilStatelessSessionBeanLocal() {
    return perilEjbReference;
}

public void setPerilStatelessSessionBeanLocal(PerilStatelessSessionBeanLocal perilEjbReference) {
    this.perilEjbReference = perilEjbReference; 
}
```

**Session Bean looks like below -**

`@Stateless(mappedName="PerilStatelessSessionBean")
@Local(PerilStatelessSessionBeanLocal.class)
public class PerilStatelessSessionBean implements PerilStatelessSessionBeanLocal {`

**I'm getting the following exception -**

*CWWAM0003E: An exception occurred while validating an annotation: com.ibm.wsspi.amm.validate.ValidationException: For method, org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.autowireBean[com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@35039510 ( org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.autowireBean )], parameters were specified, but null was the expected comparison
                                 com.ibm.wsspi.amm.validate.ValidationException: For method, org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.autowireBean[com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.util.info.impl.MethodInfoImpl@35039510 ( org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.autowireBean )], parameters were specified, but null was the expected comparison
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.validate.common.lifecycle.BaseLifecycleValidator.validateCommon(BaseLifecycleValidator.java:114)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.validate.ejb.lifecycle.BaseEJBLifecycleValidator.validate(BaseEJBLifecycleValidator.java:151)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.validate.common.lifecycle.PostConstructValidator.validate(PostConstructValidator.java:54)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.amm.merge.AbstractMergeAction.mergeMethodTargets(AbstractMergeAction.java:271)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.amm.merge.AbstractMergeAction.merge(AbstractMergeAction.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.performMergeOperations(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:472)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.merge(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.commonarchive.AnnotationsProcessorImpl.merge(AnnotationsProcessorImpl.java:132)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.commonarchive.AnnotationsProcessorImpl.merge(AnnotationsProcessorImpl.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.processEJBAnnotations(WARFileImpl.java:2523)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getEJBDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:2196)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getEJBDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:2021)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getEJBDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:2014)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.merge.ejb.manager.EJBData.getDescriptor(EJBData.java:170)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.merge.ejb.manager.EJBData.initEJBData(EJBData.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.merge.ejb.manager.EJBDataManager.getEJBData(EJBDataManager.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.merge.ejb.TransactionAttributeMergeAction.merge(TransactionAttributeMergeAction.java:115)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.performMergeOperations(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:472)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.merge(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.commonarchive.AnnotationsProcessorImpl.merge(AnnotationsProcessorImpl.java:132)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.commonarchive.AnnotationsProcessorImpl.merge(AnnotationsProcessorImpl.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.processAnnotations(WARFileImpl.java:867)
    at com.ibm.ws.webfragmerger.WebFragMergerImpl.merge(WebFragMergerImpl.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.mergeAnnotationsAndFragments(WARFileImpl.java:813)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:342)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getBindings(WARFileImpl.java:876)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getStandardBindings(WARFileImpl.java:945)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.getBindings(EARFileImpl.java:695)
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.cell.TreeBuilder.processWebModule(TreeBuilder.java:2322)
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.cell.TreeBuilder.readApplication(TreeBuilder.java:2007)
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.cell.TreeBuilder.readApplication(TreeBuilder.java:1857)
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.cell.TreeBuilder.doConfigChangePostProcessing(TreeBuilder.java:3243)
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.cell.TreeBuilder.handleConfigChange(TreeBuilder.java:3096)
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.cell.TreeBuilder.configChanged(TreeBuilder.java:3040)
    at com.ibm.ws.odc.cell.TreeBuilder$LocalEventListener.configChanged(TreeBuilder.java:5155)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.ConfigChangeHandler$ConfigChangeEventDispatcher.run(ConfigChangeHandler.java:365)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.component.ConfigChangeHandler.alarm(ConfigChangeHandler.java:167)
    at com.ibm.ejs.util.am._Alarm.run(_Alarm.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1650)*

Comment: Is this exception actually causing a problem, or is it just noise in the logs?  In any case, I suspect this is a product issue, so I upgrading to the latest service pack, and if the issue remains, then raise a PMR with IBM.